# How to add Combine compatibility to custom classes with older iOS support?

Tags: swift, combine

I create a framework and I want to support early adopters of Combine and SwiftUI for some of my providers without dropping prior iOS version support. I like declarative style and I often use observable classes/structures for variable states that could be used by a developer. How to add Combine's support without dropping iOS10+ support and without coding two different classes?

I planned to add `#if canImport(Combine)` extension to such classes so iOS13 users could use it in a native way without writing custom stores. So they could just call `.sink` or `.assign` for example and they will receive updates.

I don't know what protocol to adopt. I thought that store is a `Publisher`, but `Publisher` can't use `.send` method when something changes and I don't know how to notify `Subscriber` so.

```
public class SomeDataProvider<T> {
    private var didChangeHandler: ((T?) -> Void)?

    public var value: T? {
        didSet {
            didChangeHandler?(value)
        }
    }
    public func didChange(handler: @escaping ((T?) -> Void)) {
        self.didChangeHandler = handler
    }

    public init() {}
}
```

The best approach also is to emulate at least `.sink` (most usable) for prior versions of iOS, so we don't use two separate methods or different iOS versions.

Comment: Why not adopt reactive swift? That's what Combine is stolen from in any case.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that this repo ([OpenCombine](https://github.com/broadwaylamb/OpenCombine)) is handling, the idea you have is really great but Combine is too complicated to build. The project is in early development, that's because Combine is new to the world.